# Error getting thrown when trying to sign in with Google Auth to Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to create a google sign in option for my app. I appear to be getting back a valid Token Id from google but my app is crashing in the ios Emulator and the following error is being shown in console.

> flutter: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] Unable to parse Google id_token: ya29.A0ARrdaM_uqbYHorJh1kJXTXac7MEm2TjD.......

When I cancel the login an error is successfully being thrown from my code. Can anyone help me out?

> flutter: [firebase_auth/sign_in_canceled] The user canceled the sign-in flow.

```
@override
Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  if (googleUser != null) {
    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    if (googleAuth.idToken != null) {
      final UserCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      ));
      return UserCredential.user;
    } else {
      throw FirebaseAuthException(
        code: 'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN',
        message: 'Missing Google ID Token',
      );
    }
  } else {
    throw FirebaseAuthException(
      code: 'sign_in_canceled',
      message: 'The user canceled the sign-in flow.',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please include the error message of your terminal

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This line needed to be changed to pass the idToken...not the accessToken.

```
idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
```